# How to optimize 'group by' query and indexing on big table?

Tags: mysql, index, optimization

My table has over 300+ million records. I created a key **store_idx** consisting of columns (store_region, store_format, store_code). This is my query:

```
select store_region,
       store_format, 
       store_code,
       count(distinct basket_id), 
       min(shop_date), 
       max(shop_date) 
from basket 
group by store_region, 
         store_format, 
         store_code 
order by store_region, 
         store_format, 
         store_code;
```

When I ran explain command this was the output:

```
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows      | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | basket | NULL       | index | store_idx     | store_idx | 3069    | NULL | 305100051 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------+
```

This query is taking so long to run. How can I optimize?

Comment: how many rows does your query return? could you please add table definition? you need to add shop_date, basket_id to index or try to use two separate indexes (one with added shop_date and the second one with basket_id)

Comment: Please consider reading about [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 2):

Calculating three aggregates on a 300 million row table without a filter is going to take some time, especially if the rows have to read from disk. Without knowing anything about types and indexes, it is difficult to give any specific advice, but you may try to replace `store_idx` with an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX store_idx ON basket
    (store_region, store_format, store_code, basket_id, shop_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lennart may have the best answer.  Here is another possibility:

What is the PK now?  Assuming it is `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, then this may be good.  Change

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),
INDEX(store_region, store_format, store_code)
```

to

```
PRIMARY KEY(store_region, store_format, store_code, id),  -- to cluster data
INDEX(id),   -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```